# How to open multiple files using fopen and file pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a predetermined amount of one-dimensional double arrays and want to write each one of them to a file. For example, if I have 96 arrays, I'd like to have 96 different files containing these arrays.

I'm initializing a file as follows:

```
FILE * f=fopen("domain001.txt","w");
...
...
...
fclose(f)
```

I'd like to do this initialization as a "file pointer array". I may have a function, to which I send the number of files to be initialized, such as 96, and the function would initialize 96 text files such as domain001.txt to domain096.txt. How can I do that?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why not just create an array of file pointers and open them up one at a time?

Comment: @Foo Bah. How is it done exactly?

Comment: Note that some (most?) systems limit the number of files you can have open simultaneously.  On my Ubuntu system, the default limit is 1024, and the hard limit is 4096, but some systems (particularly older ones) might impose a lower limit.  Do you really need to have all 96 files open simultaneously?  Can you reorganize your program so it opens a file, writes to it, closes it, then opens the next one, and so forth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure i got what you want..maybe this?

```
FILE* files[FILE_N];
for(int i = 0; i < FILE_N; i++) {
    char filename[50];
    sprintf(filename, "domain%03d", i);
    files[i] = fopen(filename, "w");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something cheesy like:

```
FILE ** filelist = (FILE **) malloc(96 * sizeof(FILE*));
for(int i = 0; i != 96; ++i) {
    char buf[1024];

    // now we build the file name
    strcpy(buf, "domain"); // "domain"
    sprintf(buf+6,"%03d", i+1); // "domain001" ... "domain096")
    strcat(buf, ".txt"); // "domain001.txt" ... "domain096.txt"

    // open file
    filelist[i] = fopen(buf, "w");
}
```

and now `filelist[i]` corresponds to the `i`th file.

Comment: thank you but it fails to compile and gives the error: C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'FILE **'

Comment: sorry forgot it was C++, you need to cast it.  Updated response

Comment: Since you have a fixed number of `FILE*` objects in your array, you might as well just declare it as an array rather than using `malloc()` (or `new[]`, since you're using C++).

Comment: "I may have a function, to which I send the number of files to be initialized, such as 96, and the function would initialize 96 text files such as domain001.txt to domain096.txt." which means the list length is passed as a variable.